# Откуда компании берут список всех адресов мира/России?

Tags: yandexmapkit, яндекс-карты

Вы наверняка видели, как в приложениях с доставкой (Азбука Вкуса, Перекресток, Yandex, Delivery Club) при вводе части адреса предлагается множество вариантов. Например, я набрал

> "Пятн"

, а приложение уже предложило мне

```
Пятницкая улица 1
Пятницкая улица 2
Пятницкая улица 3
```

и т.д.
Откуда карты знают, какие адреса есть, а каких нет? Где можно взять такую базу данных, пользуясь Yandex Mapkit?

Comment: Ну у Яндекса есть свои карты. А остальные пользуются его API или аналогами от других компаний.

Comment: Для России есть государственный адресный реестр https://www.nalog.gov.ru/opendata/7707329152-fias/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Базы данных компании едва ли будут вам просто так выдавать. Но пользоваться ими вполне возможно. Зачастую даже бесплатно.

У того же Яндекса для браузерных проектов есть метод [**suggest()**](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/suggest.html), наглядный пример работы которого есть в их песочнице JavaScript API:
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/input_validation

Для мобильных проектов в MapKit также есть [suggestSession](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/android-ref/full/com/yandex/mapkit/search/SearchManager.html#createSuggestSession--) в поиске, [пример использования которого](https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-android-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/yandex/mapkitdemo/SuggestActivity.java) также есть. Подробней о работе мобильного поиска было ранее написано в их [статье на Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/company/yandex/blog/428564/).

Сами данные Яндекс собирает самостоятельно и постоянно их пополняет как собственными силами, так и за счёт правок и дополнений от пользователей их [Карт](https://yandex.ru/maps).